# Flag older duplicates in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table properties

```
source|   address   |   price   |   size   |   created_at   |duplicate
file1 |Fleet St., 1 | 230.00    | 13       | 2019-12-01     | 0
file2 |Help St.43   | 90.00     | 4        | 2018-5-5       | 0
file1 |Fleet St., 1 | 230.00    | 13       | 2019-10-01     | 0
file1 |Fleet St., 1 | 230.00    | 13       | 2017-10-01     | 0
```

I need to find duplicates based on source, address, price and size, and flag all of them as duplicates except the most recent.

Below the desired output.

```
source|   address   |   price   |   size   |   created_at   |duplicate
file1 |Fleet St., 1 | 230.00    | 13       | 2019-12-01     | 0
file2 |Help St.43   | 90.00     | 4        | 2018-5-5       | 0
file1 |Fleet St., 1 | 230.00    | 13       | 2019-10-01     | 1
file1 |Fleet St., 1 | 230.00    | 13       | 2017-10-01     | 1
```

I have come up with the following query to identify the duplicates but I don't know how to proceed.

```
SELECT
    source,
    address,
    COUNT(address),
    price,
    COUNT(price),
    size,
    COUNT(size),
    MAX(created_at)
FROM properties
GROUP BY
    source,
    address,
    price,
    size
HAVING
    COUNT(address) > 1 AND
    COUNT(price) > 1 AND
    COUNT(size) > 1 AND
    COUNT(source) > 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Whats the datatype of created_at?  Ideally that should be a `DATE` datatype

Comment: Mysql version 5.7 and created_at is Date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `update` if you want to change the value.  In this case, with a `from` and aggregation query:

```
update properties p join
       (select source, address, price, size,
               max(created_at) as max_created_at
        from properties
        group by source, address, price, size
       ) pp
       using (source, address, price, size)
    set p.is_duplicate = 1
where p.created_at < pp.max_created_at;
```

Note that this does not set the duplicate value to `0` for the most recent.  If your data instead starts with `NULL` values, then use:

```
update properties p join
       (select source, address, price, size,
               max(created_at) as max_created_at
        from properties
        group by source, address, price, size
       ) pp
       using (source, address, price, size)
    set p.is_duplicate = (p.created_at < pp.max_created_at);
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, and it's working extremely fast too!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `RANK` here, assuming you are using MySQL 8+:

```
SELECT
    source,
    address,
    price,
    size,
    created_at,
    CASE WHEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY source, address, price, size
                           ORDER BY created_at DESC) = 1
         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS duplicate
FROM properties;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can try a join to a subquery which finds the most recent `created_at` for each group:

```
SELECT
    p1.source,
    p1.address,
    p1.price,
    p1.size,
    p1.created_at,
    CASE WHEN p2.source IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS duplicate
FROM properties p1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT source, address, price, size, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
    FROM properties
    GROUP BY source, address, price, size
) p2
    ON p1.source = p2.source AND
       p1.address = p2.address AND
       p1.price = p2.price AND
       p1.size = p2.size AND
       p1.created_at = p2.max_created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS (works in any version of MySQL):

```
select t.*,
 exists(
   select 1 from properties
   where source = t.source and address = t.address and price = t.price and size = t.size
   and created_at > t.created_at
 ) duplicate 
from properties t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rmCZqkSKQ1FdcBq23K1jkz/2).
If you want to update the column `duplicate`:

```
update properties p inner join (
  select t.*,
    exists(
      select 1 from properties
      where source = t.source and address = t.address and price = t.price and size = t.size
      and created_at > t.created_at
    ) dup 
  from properties t
) t on p.source = t.source and p.address = t.address and p.price = t.price and p.size = t.size and p.created_at = t.created_at
set p.duplicate = t.dup;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rmCZqkSKQ1FdcBq23K1jkz/3).
Results:

```
| source | address      | price | size | created_at          | duplicate |
| ------ | ------------ | ----- | ---- | ------------------- | --------- |
| file1  | Fleet St., 1 | 230   | 13   | 2019-12-01 00:00:00 | 0         |
| file2  | Help St.43   | 90    | 4    | 2018-05-05 00:00:00 | 0         |
| file1  | Fleet St., 1 | 230   | 13   | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 | 1         |
| file1  | Fleet St., 1 | 230   | 13   | 2017-10-01 00:00:00 | 1         |
```